# how to convert callback to promise

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to learn about what the promise is and how to convert callback to promise. While I'm converting my code to promise I got very confused about the ref. I would very appreciate it if you show me how to convert this code as a simple example.

```
database.ref('/users').on("child_added").then(function(snap){
  var subData = snap.val();

  database.ref('/subs/' + subData.subid + '/pri/' + snap.key).once("value").then(function(userSnap) {
    var userData = userSnap.val();

    subData.name = userData.name;
    subData.age = userData.age;

    database.ref('/subs/' + subData.subid).once("value",function(subDSnap) {
      var subDData = subDSnap.val();
      subData.type = subDData.type;
      database_m.ref('/users/' + snap.key).set(subData);
    });
  });  
});
```

Comment: going to need more information. Are you using a library where the methods are said to be returning Promises? The code example you've provided is too shallow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Promise is not a replacement for every type of callback; rather it's an abstraction around one particular task that will either succeed once or fail once. The code you're converting looks more like an EventEmitter, where an event can occur *multiple* times, so replacing `.on('child_added', ...)` with a Promise implementation is not a good fit.

However, later on, you have a `.once(...)` call. That's a bit closer to a Promise in that it will only complete once. So if you really wanted to convert that, here's what it could look like:

```
function get(database, url) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    database
      .ref(url)
      .once('value', resolve)
      .once('error', reject);
  });
}

database.ref('/users').on("child_added", function(snap) {
  var subData = snap.val();

  get(database, '/subs/' + subData.subid + '/pri/' + snap.key)
    .then(function(userSnap) {
      var userData = userSnap.val();

      subData.name = userData.name;
      subData.age = userData.age;

      return get(database, '/subs/' + subData.subid);
    })
    .then(function(subDSnap) {
      var subDData = subDSnap.val();
      subData.type = subDData.type;
      database_m.ref('/users/' + snap.key).set(subData);
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
      // handle errors
    });
  });  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand the question and if your "on" is returning a promise or just listening, but in your code you have nested '.then', which is not the common way to deal with promises and I am not sure that's what you wanted to achieve here.

You could do (assuming that the on function returns a promise, which I doubt)

```
 database.ref('/users').on("child_added")
.then(function(snap){/* do something with the first part of your snap function*/})
.then (results => {/* do something else, such as your second ref call*/})
.catch(error => {/* manage the error*/})
```

To learn about promises, there are many examples online but what I really liked is the  [promise tutorial at google](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/promises), with this nice snippet that explains it

```
var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  // do a thing, possibly async, then…

  if (/* everything turned out fine */) {
    resolve("Stuff worked!");
  }
  else {
    reject(Error("It broke"));
  }
});
```

then, once you have the function that returns this promise, you can start doing

```
.then(...)
.then(...)
.then(...)
.catch(...)
```

Comment: what should I do when ref is changed?

Comment: so I am not sure I entirely get your code, as @Sgnl more details would help. But in  general, you need to have somewhere some function that returns a promise. do you have that? is database.ref....on.. returning a promise, or are you just listening for some event. once you have a promise, you can start chaining .then().then().then() to specify what you want to do in sequence